# ASP.NET Entity Framework update model data and related data in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a problem to update my model data and related data in one view. So, I have two models.

1st model describes an event:

```cs
public class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        Guests = new List<Guest>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EventTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public int Room { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string UserPhone { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Guest> Guests { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string DateToString
    {
        get { return EventDate.ToShortDateString(); }
        set { EventDate = DateTime.Parse(value); }
    }
```

And 2nd model describes the guests:

```cs
public class Guest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Vārds, uzvārds")]
    public string GuestName { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

For one event, there can be several guests, the relation is one-to-many.

Now, I have created an edit view, which display information about the event and guests attached to the event. the code of view is:

```asp
 <div class="panel-body">
        @{
            @:<dl class="dl-horizontal">
            if (Model.Guests != null)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Guests.Count; i++)
                {
                    @:<dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Guests[i].GuestName)</dt>
                    @:<dt>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Guests[i].GuestName)</dt>
                    }
            }
             @:</dl>
        }
    </div>
```

In my controller, in post method I successfully receive the model with edited guest entries. But, when I set the state of context to modified i receive error:

> Attaching an entity of type 'GuestAudit.Models.Guest' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

My controller code is:

```cs
 public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,EventName,Room,EventDate,DateToString,EventTime,UserPhone,Status,Guests")] Event @event)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            @event.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
            db.Entry(@event).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(@event);
    }
```

This line of code, gives me the error:

> db.Entry(@event).State = EntityState.Modified;

It is possible, to edit model data and related data in one view?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. So, I modified the View code an add hidden element for each related record. Now the view code looks like:

```asp
<div class="panel-body">
        @{
            @:<dl class="dl-horizontal">
            if (Model.Guests != null)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Guests.Count; i++)
                {
                    @:<dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Guests[i].GuestName)</dt>
                    @:<dt>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Guests[i].GuestName)</dt>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Guests[i].EventID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Guests[i].ID)
                }
            }
             @:</dl>
        }
    </div>
```

And controller looks like

```cs
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,EventName,Room,EventDate,DateToString,EventTime,UserPhone,Status,Guests")] Event @event)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            @event.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
            @event.Guests.ForEach(f => db.Entry(f).State = EntityState.Modified);
            db.Entry(@event).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(@event);
    }
```